# Https Ajax Call Cross Domain on Session Timeout

Tags: java, jquery, spring, tomcat, nginx

My web application is doing re-writes to HTTPS from HTTP on every page.  The application is Spring 3, with a jquery front end.  The re-writes are handled by nginx, which I have no experience in, or access to.

The problem is on session timeout when a user does an AJAX call,

1. the page is on HTTPS
2. the ajax call goes the correct HTTPS url
3. spring security filter sees the session is invalid and does a redirect to the session invalidated handler url, but uses HTTP.

This in turn caused a cross domain error for the front end.  I've talked with the sys-admin about this but he couldn't think of any solutions.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the connector in tomcat was not setup properly, needed to add these attributes to ensure the URIs are correct

http://www.dhis2.org/doc/snapshot/en/implementer/html/ch08s03.html

scheme="https" proxyPort="443